# Debug Java SSL Handshake using -Djavax.net.debug=all

Tags: java, security, ssl, ssl-certificate

My Node.js client is connecting to a Java server with SSL.  It seems to work up until the CertificateVerify where then I get a cache session, and my client prints SSL Couldn't Authorize.

Here is a snippet of the Java server debug statements logged from the ssl handshake using -Djavax.net.debug=all.  The problem is, Java does not explicitly raise any red flags like couldn't verify signature.  This is the tail of the log where it stops. Note: I added an ellipses after the Cache Server Session at the end of the log.

Can anyone help me decipher this log output to determine why the ssl handshake is failing?  I'm guessing that ultimately it can't verify the signature of the certificate, but I do not see this being explicitly stated.

```
pool-1-thread-2, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 264
*** CertificateVerify
Signature Algorithm SHA512withRSA
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 264
0000: 0F 00 01 04 06 01 01 00   1E F6 13 87 8C 77 81 2D  .............w.-
0010: E3 33 EB E0 8F 80 49 C6   90 F9 B5 4C 9B A0 69 77  .3....I....L..iw
0020: B1 14 6C E3 B2 15 15 1F   26 D5 69 31 64 36 0D D1  ..l.....&.i1d6..
0030: DA AD BA 58 BF 76 6D 25   1D 49 BA 4A C6 80 1C 49  ...X.vm%.I.J...I
0040: DC 5B D8 F0 FC B3 34 86   93 71 0D 3D 92 DB AB 0E  .[....4..q.=....
0050: 6A 34 62 FC F5 09 61 65   68 12 64 BB 6F 6E 39 96  j4b...aeh.d.on9.
0060: BC C6 40 D4 A1 63 4D 0E   68 61 02 8E 14 4B DF 6D  ..@..cM.ha...K.m
0070: B1 C2 D6 D5 E6 09 19 E9   31 A6 20 07 44 BB AD 43  ........1. .D..C
0080: D4 3C 91 9C 56 FC A8 70   8B 5C 8D 87 F2 61 30 CA  .<..V..p.\...a0.
0090: 6B 82 88 FA 3D B3 27 84   12 FE EF 2B 51 3A DD 5B  k...=.'....+Q:.[
00A0: 0E 03 D6 44 E9 B8 04 EF   62 4B 7A 51 7E 6D 85 79  ...D....bKzQ.m.y
00B0: 1A 78 C8 5E 21 C8 E8 CA   2A 7D 2F 5E 6C 90 1B 00  .x.^!...*./^l...
00C0: B5 97 5F 8D FC D5 C3 D8   ED 2D 05 B6 DA 51 16 B7  .._......-...Q..
00D0: 39 14 44 46 DE 80 DD 98   31 F8 B5 DD E8 89 8C 64  9.DF....1......d
00E0: 4E DF 3C 99 38 10 87 F4   D0 67 4E C3 AA FE 25 F3  N.<.8....gN...%.
00F0: 7E F1 48 60 52 09 2C 2B   C4 32 A4 58 92 3E 15 4A  ..H`R.,+.2.X.>.J
0100: DA 11 CB 19 45 16 5D 79                            ....E.]y
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 14 03 03 00 01                                     .....
[Raw read]: length = 1
0000: 01                                                 .
pool-1-thread-2, READ: TLSv1.2 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 16 03 03 00 50                                     ....P
[Raw read]: length = 80
0000: CE F7 6C D4 32 5C 12 6E   02 47 11 1E DA C8 7C 13  ..l.2\.n.G......
0010: F0 F5 92 42 82 3D 58 FF   70 A3 05 D9 1F D8 00 1E  ...B.=X.p.......
0020: 88 77 06 11 78 B5 A7 AA   23 69 D5 54 E9 22 78 D6  .w..x...#i.T."x.
0030: 08 A8 B2 D8 AF CE 78 91   34 28 78 6B 50 8D 7E 32  ......x.4(xkP..2
0040: 1A 30 79 ED 31 51 FD 8D   79 59 5A 9D 99 27 B4 25  .0y.1Q..yYZ..'.%
pool-1-thread-2, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 80
Padded plaintext after DECRYPTION:  len = 80
0000: A8 92 6E 76 A7 44 8F 3F   0A 85 B0 7B 5F D9 21 CE  ..nv.D.?...._.!.
0010: 14 00 00 0C 86 62 B5 EF   19 0C 5C C2 DF 60 35 5C  .....b....\..`5\
0020: 84 2D 2D 20 C9 87 0A 37   33 44 5D E9 95 2D 3B B9  .-- ...73D]..-;.
0030: E3 50 F1 31 1C 54 F9 41   FB 4E C4 B6 81 C5 DF 78  .P.1.T.A.N.....x
0040: 0F 0F 0F 0F 0F 0F 0F 0F   0F 0F 0F 0F 0F 0F 0F 0F  ................
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 134, 98, 181, 239, 25, 12, 92, 194, 223, 96, 53, 92 }
***
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 16
0000: 14 00 00 0C 86 62 B5 EF   19 0C 5C C2 DF 60 35 5C  .....b....\..`5\
pool-1-thread-2, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
[Raw write]: length = 6
0000: 14 03 03 00 01 01                                  ......
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 166, 60, 137, 232, 242, 208, 180, 127, 89, 133, 80, 93 }
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 16
0000: 14 00 00 0C A6 3C 89 E8   F2 D0 B4 7F 59 85 50 5D  .....<......Y.P]
Padded plaintext before ENCRYPTION:  len = 80
0000: 9C F6 B8 F4 10 05 57 5C   DE 38 27 7A 82 F5 04 88  ......W\.8'z....
0010: 14 00 00 0C A6 3C 89 E8   F2 D0 B4 7F 59 85 50 5D  .....<......Y.P]
0020: 73 1C 58 7B 9D FD 88 E4   40 1A 04 AB A3 B3 57 38  s.X.....@.....W8
0030: 7B 22 19 CB F0 24 AE 16   69 63 04 F9 9E 20 7D 00  ."...$..ic... ..
0040: 0F 0F 0F 0F 0F 0F 0F 0F   0F 0F 0F 0F 0F 0F 0F 0F  ................
pool-1-thread-2, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 80
[Raw write]: length = 85
0000: 16 03 03 00 50 AB AE B3   92 D6 B2 9B D4 3F 51 A7  ....P........?Q.
0010: F6 FF B8 11 FF 81 26 33   2F 70 64 71 FF 33 F3 DA  ......&3/pdq.3..
0020: EB B8 9E 5E 66 69 49 20   05 0F 1A A2 C1 C6 81 EC  ...^fiI ........
0030: 07 23 7E C8 26 11 49 8F   02 1F 53 8F 49 26 30 13  .#..&.I...S.I&0.
0040: DA 10 33 9F 0A 94 B5 39   86 C8 5F D9 8A 22 49 68  ..3....9.._.."Ih
0050: C1 31 0A 7D CE                                     .1...
%% Cached server session: ...
```

More helpful information.  I've checked the expiration of the certificate.  It expires November 2044, so I'm assured that the hand shake isn't failing due to an expired certificate.

Comment: This just shows a competed SSL handshake. There is no error here. 'Couldn't authorise' is not a Java message. It is a message printed by your application, under circumstances which you have not disclosed. You need to provide the code that printed it in your question. Presumably you got an exception, in which case you must also provide the full exception and stack trace in your question. Not answerable as is.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment of the EJP, I decided to dig into the client error message.  I added a debug statement that printed the error the client was getting, which was the following:

```
Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames
```

I have a check in the client for this string, but I upgraded to node v0.12 and it appears they added some extra output in that statement.  The logic currently is to just ignore this error, and continue with the encrypted session.

Thanks for the help.