# SSLHandShakeException when connecting through HttpsUrlConnection

Tags: java, ssl

```java
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.connect();
response = connection.getResponseCode();
```

I have this piece of code, and I am getting SSLHandShakeException all the time.
Can somebody elaborate where the issue can be?

Comment: Many different reasons end with this Exception. Have a look at [Debug Java SSL Handshake using -Djavax.net.debug=all](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29085950/7748072)

Comment: I added switch  Djavax.net.debug=all  and run from command line.
It started downloading and works as charm. Why it doesn't work without
debug=all option?

Comment: It worked only once..and this option doesn't print any output to shell.

Comment: This option works always and prints to the default log. If you're not printing anything it means you're not doing anything, check somewhere else why the code is not executed.